# how to display in dashboard_image_details in next intent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

my json  how to display in dashboard_image_details   in intent 
retrofit 2 how to display in recyclerview

```
{
    "dashboard_info": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "week_id": "1",
            "week_name": "week one",
            "color": "#9a94c7",
            "week_title": "Fruits",
            "password": "admin1",
            "week_image": "http://192.168.0.2/littlezebra/school_uploads/week_images/1/fruit.png",
            "dashboard_image_details": [
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "image_title": "Apple",
                    "image": "http://192.168.0.2/littlezebra/school_uploads/dashboard_images/1/6/app.png",
                    "color": "#c88dac"
                },


            ]


        }
}
```

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want like:

Fruit
Apple Banana etc

(View like play store vertical scroll(Category like fruits) and horizontal scroll(items like Apple))

So your first adapter showing dashboard_info

Then need to add list or recyclerview inside first adapter xml file.(for dashboard_image_details )

And then need to call second adapter from first adapters 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){} method.

Second adapter will be normal just with recyclerview with horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

public class dashboard {

```
@SerializedName("dashboard_info")
@Expose
private ArrayList<dash> list;


public ArrayList<dash> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<dash> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
}
```

create another class for dashboard details

```
public class dash {

@SerializedName("week_title")
@Expose
private String name ;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String email;


@SerializedName("dashboard_image_details")
private ArrayList<image> list;

public ArrayList<image> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<image> list) {
    this.list = list;
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

I have used the listview with base adapter code in getview method is below

```
  dash em = model.get(i);

    txtemail.setText(em.getEmail());


   image img = em.getList().get(0);

    txtname.setText(em.getName() + img.getImgtitle());
```

If having doubts then go ahead...